# How do I take my JSON data and put it into a MySQL table with Python?

Tags: python, mysql, json

I have a huge JSON file of a database of movies. I also have a MySQL database with a movies table. I currently have a python list with all the JSON data, but I am stuck on how is the best way to turn that list into data I can put into my MySQL table.
TLDR: How do I turn my Python list in JSON object format into a executable structure for MySQL. Here is the Python code:

```
import mysql.connector
import json

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    passwd="",
    database="testdb"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sqlFormula = "INSERT INTO movies (title, year, cast, genres) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"

with open('movies.json', encoding="utf8") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

print(data)

mycursor.execute(sqlFormula, data)

mydb.commit()
```

And here is a snippet of the JSON movie file:

```
    "title": "The Haunting in Connecticut",
    "year": 2009,
    "cast": [
      "Virginia Madsen",
      "Kyle Gallner",
      "Martin Donovan",
      "Elias Koteas",
      "Amanda Crew"
    ],
    "genres": [
      "Horror"
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "He's Just Not That Into You",
    "year": 2009,
    "cast": [
      "Ben Affleck",
      "Jennifer Aniston",
      "Drew Barrymore",
      "Jennifer Connelly",
      "Kevin Connelly",
      "Bradley Cooper",
      "Ginnifer Goodwin",
      "Scarlett Johansson",
      "Justin Long"
    ],
    "genres": [
      "Romance",
      "Comedy"
    ]
  }
```

MySQL movie table has a column for each title, year, cast, and genre. I am new to python, but my first guess would be to iterate through the list and save each title, year, etc as a variable then put that into another list and put that into my mycursor.execute(sqlFormula, combined list). If that is a bad solution or impossible, I wouldn't know. But if there is a better solution that I just don't know please help.

Comment: MySQL can parse JSON data and insert it into the table. You don't need to do this on python side. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html

Comment: @Akina Yeah the MySQL workbench also has a great table data import wizard. I am mainly trying to just learn and see if things like that are possible. Also just generally overwhelmed by MySQL so I tried to relate it to Python.